# is Chvátal Graph 4-critic?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm working in excersice 14.2.3 from Bondy and Murty, Graph Theory, 2008. This excersice asks to show that Chvátal graph is 4-critic on chromatic number, but I'm not really sure that this claim is correct. I read somwhere that it is false if we delete "two appropriately chosen edges" but it doesn't says which of them. So far I proved that any vertex-deletion results in a 3-chromatic graph, which doesn't represent a problem so far. Now I need to check what happens with edge-deletion, but I don't see how to solve this without using the long way wich is finding de chromatic number of 5 different graphs which result by deleting one of each "different distinguishable type of edge". I also tried with the independence number but I didn't get to any conclusion.
My question is, do any of you know any simplest way to get a conclution about it? Thanks in advance. You can find the graph in the next link

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chvátal_graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chv%C3%A1tal_graph)

Comment: Would you mind including an image/description of the graph in question in order to make your question more self-contained? Embedding the image from Wikipedia would be fine.

Comment: done, thanks by the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the four edges highlighted below can be deleted from the Chvátal graph to get another $4$-chromatic graph:

[image]

This is not hard to check by hand using the fact that the Chvátal graph is 4-chromatic. If we pick one of these edges to delete, any hypothetical 3-coloring of the resulting graph must give the same color to the endpoints of the deleted edge: otherwise, it would be a 3-coloring of the Chvátal graph. So we can contract the edge instead, getting (for example) the following graph:

[image]

In this graph, the contracted vertex is part of several triangles; if we color all three vertices of a triangle different colors, and try to complete the result to a 3-coloring, there is a forced decision at every step until we reach a contradiction.

Comment: thank you a lot